# Finding values from dataframe by filtering using keys, 0 or NA if key not found

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a vector called portfolio, which is a length 100 vector containing 100 stock tickers.  I also have a dataframe called data, which contains a column for tickers and a column for returns.  data contains the returns data for many more than the 100 stocks we are interested in, but it may not have data on all 100 stocks.

I have been using:

```
portfolio.index = portfolio %in% data$ticker
```

to get the indices in my portfolio where the stocks have returns data.  This vector is length 100.

I'm trying to get a vector of length 100 that contains the returns of the 100 stocks in the portfolio (and I would like the order of the returns in the vector to be the same as the order of the stocks in the portfolio).  If the return doesn't exist in our dataframe data, then the value can be 0 or NA.

I tried doing:

```
data$returns[data$ticker %in% portfolio]
```

but the problem is that there may only be 90 stocks of my 100 that have returns, so then the vector this gives out is of length 90 with no 0 or NA values.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps convert your vector first to a `data.frame`, then merge with `data`

```
portfolio <- data.frame(ticker = portfolio)
merge(portfolio, data, all = TRUE)
```

Comment: Maybe also `data[ match(portfolio, data$ticker), ]` (I haven't tested it.)